# could not resolve property: date

Tags: grails, groovy, gsp, named-query

I am working on some codes to query a specific date.

I have this in my Person.groovy:

```
Date dateCreated
static constraints = {
dateCreated type:"date"
}

static namedQueries = {
dateMe{ q->
eq("date.created", q)   
}
}
```

And I call it in a gsp like this:

```
<g:set var="dated" value="${Person.dateMe(personInstance.dateCreated)}"/>
```

But I got this error "could not resolve property: date of: project.Person"
Am I missing something? should I format the date before querying? Please help, I would highly appreciate it.

Answer (score 5):

I believe

```
eq("date.created", q)
```

Should be

```
eq("dateCreated", q)
```